# Chrome console shows me "Navigated to http://localhost...."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Chrome console shows me "Navigated to http://localhost...." in blue letters

Image: 
[image]

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of that message?

Comment: This is a link to the screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/navigated.jpg

Comment: Happens when I press F5

Comment: Does it show up on every page?

Comment: No. With this java(using jquery):     function w(id) { return $(id); }

w.prototype = {
 hide: function () {
    this.e.style.display = 'none';
    return this;
   }};

w.hola = function(){
 console.log("Hola");
 };
$(document).ready(function(e) {
w("div").hide();    
w.hola();

});

Comment: Now, yes. it shows me this on every page!

Comment: Means to be a Chrome problem...

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This is a feature on chrome to separate between page logs, when you have the "preserve logs" option checked. It shouldn't show up if you uncheck that box and reload the page.

It's just telling you that the browser change to another page.

Comment: Same in Firefox. :)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is just telling you that the browser location changed to another page. You can stop it with the Chrome settings.

Just go to `Chrome inspect > settings > preferences > network > preserve log` and uncheck it.