# How to detect route changes with react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to detect if a route change has occurred so that I can change a variable to true.

I've looked through these questions:
1. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554
2. [How to listen to route changes in react router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4)
3. [Detect Route Change with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router)

None of them have worked for me. Is there a clear way to call a function when a route change occurs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your use case? Maybe there is another solution instead of listening for route changes?

Comment: I'm using socket.io, but have multiple pages. The disconnect function socket.io provides cannot tell the difference between route changes and a user leaving the entire site. If I can tell there's not a route change, then I know the user is leaving the site when using window.onbeforeunload. @sn42

Answer (score 25):

One way is to use the `withRouter` higher-order component.

**[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/2jonpprp6y?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fcomponents%2FApp.js)** (click the hyperlinks to change routes and view the results in the displayed console)

> You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
            console.log('Route change!');
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                ...routes
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(props => <App {...props}/>);
```

---

Another example that uses url params:

If you were changing profile routes from `/profile/20` to `/profile/32`

And your route was defined as `/profile/:userId`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.userId !== prevProps.match.params.userId) {
        console.log('Route change!');
    }
}
```

Comment: My route changes: from /profile to /conversations or /tour to /matches. @wdm

Comment: @Hunter690 Do you need to know specifically which route you've changed to or just that the route has changed?

Comment: just that my route changed

Comment: @Hunter690 see edits I added another example using `withRouter`

Comment: I tried using withRouter, but I can't get componentDidUpdate to run for some reason (I added a console.log and didn't get anything on the console)

Comment: @Hunter690 Check out this live example. Click the links in the render window to see the console on route change: https://codesandbox.io/embed/2jonpprp6y?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fcomponents%2FApp.js

Answer (score 17):

With React Hooks, it should be as simple as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { pathname } = location;
    console.log('New path:', pathname);
}, [location.pathname]);
```

By passing `location.pathname` in the second array argument, means you are saying to useEffect to only re-run if `location.pathname` changes.

Live example with code source: https://codesandbox.io/s/detect-route-path-changes-with-react-hooks-dt16i

Comment: This does not work for me. The callback is only called once, to show the initial path. But after pathname changes again, the new path is not output in tthe console.

Comment: I just made a simple React app on Codesandbox, it's working like charm, please check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/detect-route-path-changes-with-react-hooks-dt16i

Comment: I tried the same code and it didn't work in my app... I don't know... Thanks. I will upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, you can share with me you code so I could help :)

Comment: I decided to no longer use react-router and I switched to [hookrouter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hookrouter)

Comment: cool, that's should be the right path if you are starting a new project, but for big and mid sized projects, it's a bit hard to refactor the whole thing to hookrouter. good luck

Comment: What if ```hash``` or ```search``` changes?

Comment: It doesn't matter, we just tell useEffect to re-run if the `pathname` changes.

Answer (score 6):

React Router v5 now detects the route changes automatically thanks to hooks. Here's [the example from the team](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/?fbclid=IwAR1WHJKKeF0rO_-jW31mRCatWq5o143OvgyURn6R3uGlHNQ_dqs3QQ4ddLs) behind it:

```
import { Switch, useLocation } from 'react-router'

function usePageViews() {
  let location = useLocation()

  useEffect(
    () => {
      ga.send(['pageview', location.pathname])
    },
    [location]
  )
}

function App() {
  usePageViews()
  return <Switch>{/* your routes here */}</Switch>
}
```

This example sends a "page view" to Google Analytics (`ga`) every time the URL changes.

Comment: The problem is that it updates on the same route because the location.key changes every time. If anything you need to listen for location.pathname in your effect

Answer (score 2):

When component is specified as `<Route>`'s `component` property, React Router 4 (RR4) passes to it few additional properties: `match`, `location` and `history`.

Then u should use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to compare `location` objects before and after update (remember ES object comparison rules). Since location objects are immutable, they will never match. Even if u navigate to the same location.

```
  componentDidUpdate(newProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== newProps.location) {
      this.handleNavigation();
    }
  }
```

`withRouter` should be used when you need to access these properties within an arbitrary component that is not specified as a `component` property of any Route. Make sure to wrap your app in `<BrowserRouter>` since it provides all the necessary API, otherwise these methods will only work in components contained within `<BrowserRouter>`.

There are cases when user decides to reload the page via navigation buttons instead of dedicated interface in browsers. But comparisons like this:

```
this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname
```

will make it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

How about tracking the length of the history object in your application state? The history object provided by react-router increases in length each time a new route is traversed. See image below.

[image]

`ComponentDidMount` and `ComponentWillUnMount` check:
[image]

Comment: I tried to do that, but I have to know if its a route change before the next page loads since I'm using window.onbeforeunload.

Comment: You can check the whether or not the length increases in `componentWillUnmount`. You can initialize the length in componentDidMount and check if you are going to another route in componentWillUnmount because the length will increase before mounting new component ... see second screenshot. Hope it works!

Comment: interesting idea; I tried to just print out `history` in a `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and nothing came out the console. I have another question; in the second screenshot, there's a `Navigated to ...` print out; do you know how to access that in the code?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can access that from the code. It's part of Chrome Dev Tools: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349285/chrome-console-shows-me-navigated-to-http-localhost

Comment: Do your route components have `history` on props? Verify using React Dev Tools to see what props are on <Tour>. If history is not on props, maybe switch from `Route path='tour' component={Tour}` to `Route path='tour' render={(props) => <Tour {...props} />` to ensure the history object is available on your route components.

Answer (score 0):

React use Component-Based Architecture. So, why don't we obey this rule?

You can see [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2opxlwm85).

Each page must be wrapped by an HOC, this will detect changing of page automatically.

**Home**

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import withBase from "./withBase";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Welcome Home!!!</p>
    <NavLink to="/login">Go to login page</NavLink>
  </div>
);

export default withBase(Home);
```

**withBase HOC**

```
import React from "react";

export default WrappedComponent =>
  class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.handleChangePage();
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent />;
    }
  };
```