# React TypeScript: Call function on route change using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I expect useEffect to console log but the project fails to compile and gives an error in terminal `Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals` I dont have to use the useEffect would be happy if I can get a function to fire each time the location changes

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
import { Context } from "./components/context";
import { Layout } from "./components/layout";
import { Home } from './routes/home';
import { NotFound } from './routes/not-found';

const Router: React.FC = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('location changed')
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ global, setGlobal }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route render={({location}) => ( //<-------- this is the location!!!
          <Layout>
            <TransitionGroup>
              <CSSTransition timeout={450} classNames='fade' key={location.key}>
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} />
                  <Route exact path = '/my/profile/' component = {Home} />
                  <Route component = {NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
              </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
          </Layout>
        )} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export { Router };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect route changes with react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459919/how-to-detect-route-changes-with-react-router-v4)

Comment: That question is not specific to typescript or functional components as such the responses are all showing answers in class based components

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-descriptive. You did not declare the variable name `location` anywhere. If it is a global variable, you [need to declare](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) it like so:

```
Filename: global.d.ts
declare var location: type
```